# moving opengts from localhost to live host

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

is it possible to manually set up the java runtime and compiler resources in a host that doesn't support java, or do I have to select a host that support java jsp.

Comment: Java won't be supported where Java isn't supported.

Comment: Whether you can install Java to the server will depend on the specification of the server.